# Spring Security SAML build from source compilation error, dependency set to test not compile

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

I was trying to build 1.0.1.RELEASE from the source (grabbed the zip from github).  I was experiencing the below errors.  To get the build to succeed, I edited the dependencies and set commons-logging dependency from test to compile, so Log could be found by the compiler.  Since this was a release tag, I'm wondering if there was actually an issue that is actually on my end for building it from the exact pom.xml which came from the tag.

Build log excerpt:

```
[INFO] Compiling 98 source files to /Users/jsimon/Documents/opensources/spring-security-saml-1.0.1.RELEASE/core/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/jsimon/Documents/opensources/spring-security-saml-1.0.1.RELEASE/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/saml/SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.java:[135,22] error: cannot access Log
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.223s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jul 30 10:32:51 EDT 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/310M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project spring-security-saml2-core: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/jsimon/Documents/opensources/spring-security-saml-1.0.1.RELEASE/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/saml/SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.java:[135,22] error: cannot access Log
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project spring-security-saml2-core:     Compilation failure
/Users/jsimon/Documents/opensources/spring-security-saml-1.0.1.RELEASE/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/saml/SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.java:[135,22] error: cannot access Log

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
/Users/jsimon/Documents/opensources/spring-security-saml-1.0.1.RELEASE/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/saml/SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.java:[135,22] error: cannot access Log

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:656)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

dependency snippet:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too and changed the **scope** of "commons-logging" dependency from **test** to **compile** and the problem resolved.
So it seems it is not an issue on your end but on the pom file.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to build is with gradle, it seems like you are using Maven? Run `git clone git@github.com:spring-projects/spring-security-saml.git`, `git checkout tags/rb.1.0.1.RELEASE` and `gradlew build`. This runs well on both continuous integration server and my machine.